# How do I retrieve the text of a cell comment

Tags: excel, vba

I find lots of examples for creating but none for retrieving the text of a cell comment. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Range.Comment.Text` seems to work without any problem here...

(e. g. `if not ActiveCell.Comment is nothing then  debug.print ActiveCell.Comment.Text`)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what I was doing but it was generating an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try going for:

```
Dim comtext as string

If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
        comtext = ""
        Else
        comtext = ActiveCell.Comment.Text
        End If
```

As for me, if you want to paste comment text as other cell value you might need to use:

`Selection.ClearFormats`

since sometimes comment text which you pasted or set cell value might be invisible at first.

PS. This is my first post ever on this side, so I've just started learning the ropes.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Option Explicit


Sub ExtractComments()
Dim ExComment As Comment
Dim OneCommentThreaded As CommentThreaded
Dim OneReply As Excel.CommentThreaded
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
  If ws.Name = "Comments" Then
  i = 1
  ws.Columns("A:X").EntireColumn.Delete
  End If
Next ws
    
If i = 0 Then
  Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
  ws.Name = "Comments"
Else: Set ws = Worksheets("Comments")
End If
ws.Range("A1").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'Set headings
  ws.Range("A2").Value = "Lp"
  ws.Range("B2").Value = "Sheet"
  ws.Range("C2").Value = "Cell"
  ws.Range("D2").Value = "Commented text"
  ws.Range("E2").Value = "Comment"
  ws.Range("F2").Value = "Author"
  ws.Range("G2").Value = "Date"
  ws.Range("H2").Value = "Type of comment"
  With ws.Range("A2:H2")
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238)
    .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 30
    .Columns("D:F").ColumnWidth = 30
    .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 15
    .Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 30
  End With

  With ws.Range("A1:B1").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
'Retrieve old comments
For Each CurrentSheet In Worksheets
    'loop for old style comments
    For Each ExComment In CurrentSheet.Comments
     ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
     ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = CurrentSheet.Name
     ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2) = ExComment.Parent.Address
     ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3) = ExComment.Parent.Value
     ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4) = Right(ExComment.Text, Len(ExComment.Text) - InStr(1, ExComment.Text, ":"))
     ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5) = ExComment.Author
     ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 7) = "Note"
   
    Next ExComment
    'loop for new style threaded comments
     For Each OneCommentThreaded In CurrentSheet.CommentsThreaded
        
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = CurrentSheet.Name
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2) = OneCommentThreaded.Parent.Address
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3) = OneCommentThreaded.Parent.Value
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4) = OneCommentThreaded.Text
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5) = OneCommentThreaded.Author.Name
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 6) = Format(OneCommentThreaded.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 7) = "Threaded comment"
  
              For Each OneReply In OneCommentThreaded.Replies
                With OneReply
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = CurrentSheet.Name
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2) = OneReply.Parent.Parent.Address
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3) = OneReply.Parent.Parent.Value
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4) = OneReply.Text
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 5) = OneReply.Author.Name
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 6) = Format(OneReply.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
      ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 7) = "REPLY ON Threaded comment"
                              
                End With
            Next OneReply
       
    Next OneCommentThreaded
Next CurrentSheet

  ws.Range("A2:H100000").WrapText = False
  ws.Range("A2:H2").AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.