# Why can I not find comments on a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, comments

I'm trying to put a comment on a cell, and later read the comment. The line to put the comment works - I can see it on the sheet and see its contents:

Range("A1").AddCommentThreaded ("Comment1")

The text to read the comment does not find anything:

```
Sub testComments()
    For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
        MsgBox cmt.Text
    Next cmt
End Sub
```

also:

```
Range("A1").comment
```

is nothing. (BTW, the result is the same if I manually create the comment). Any suggestions as to what is going on? (Windows 10, Office 365 current version).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24921051/9191617

Comment: The `Threaded` is a clue that you're not working with a regular/legacy `Comment` here, but with a [`CommentThreaded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentthreaded).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Key revision: 
    For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.CommentsThreaded